# WSO2 CEP/DAS - MQTT connection not reachable MqttException (0) - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep

I found that when CEP/DAS receive an MQTT stream event that has **null** value in a STRING attribute, fire the java.lang.NullPointerException and close the MQTT connection.

Here is the example

**WORKS** (sensorName has a value)

```
 {
     "event": {
         "metaData": {
             "timestamp": 4354643,
             "isPowerSaverEnabled": false,
             "sensorId": 900,
             "sensorName": "temperature"
         },
         "correlationData": {
             "longitude": 4.504343,
             "latitude": 20.44345
         },
         "payloadData": {
             "humidity": 5.0,
             "sensorValue": 422
         }
     }
 }
```

**FAILS** (when sensorName is null)

```
 {
     "event": {
         "metaData": {
             "timestamp": 4354643,
             "isPowerSaverEnabled": false,
             "sensorId": 900,
             "sensorName": null
         },
         "correlationData": {
             "longitude": 4.504343,
             "latitude": 20.44345
         },
         "payloadData": {
             "humidity": 5.0,
             "sensorValue": 422
         }
     }
 }
```

To workaround this we are sending "" instead the null value, but there is a way to define that an attribute at the stream can support null values?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it. This is fixed in the latest branch. It seems a issue with the json mapper.

Comment: Thank you!!. The fix will be available in the 3.1.0 version of DAS?